# Layering Panels in Java for Game/Simulation type Application

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayer

I am trying to create simulation type application, within my JFrame I want to create two layers one for the background which is drawn once and remains the same, the top layer takes care of all the animations and active objects apart from them it is transparent so you can see the background underneath.

My questions are:

Can I use JPanels to achieve this, apperently JPanels wont layer on top of each other, is this correct?

Jlayers, all ive seen from Jlayers are mostly decorative implementations, would it be suitable to run a swing timer inside it and repaint multiple items on top of the parent?

Does the top layer have to be the child of the background layer or can it be created within the JFrame?

Are there are other swing components that could acheive this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want to layer multiple component it is preferable to use the `JLayeredPane`. There is one more option you can do, i.e. `GlassPane` with `JPanel` as you want to repaint it multiple times or I say render the components, `JPanel` will allow you to do this apart from that background won't affect on `glasspane`. But be sure that while rendering the components if you try to refresh whole `JFrame` it will be performance issue with GUI, it may be bit `laggy`. You can use Swing's timer class to perform an ticker based operation.

Comment: I have a swing timer in place  and the JFrame wont be refreshed so i should be good on performance, Im going to try a spike using the JLayeredPane and see if it works, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use JPanels to achieve this, apperently JPanels wont layer on top of each other, is this correct?

You could use a BorderLayout on each panel and then add one panel to another. You would also need to make the top panels non-opaque. Probably not the best design.

> Jlayers are mostly decorative implementations
>   Yes, JLayer is for decoration.

`JLayeredPane` is probably what you are looking for. It will allow you do use multiple layers and it will manage the layers for you. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I've created the jlayeredPane and it works but the problem i have now is transperency, the top layer is the default grey and cannot see the background, setOpaque(); does not solve it?

Comment: @user3081855, I suggested you need to make it non-opaque. That is `setOpaque( false )`.